# Finding Strings on the text file - Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I would like to ask if how can I find strings (3 or 5 words) on the text file with conditions. If the strings was found then a certain variable will become  equal to 1.

Scenario

I have a batch file will run every 12:01 AM. This batch file have multiple commands inside. Please see below:

1. Tail logger
2. Log checker
3. Restarter

Tail logger - This was the first function will run on the batch file. It will  tail log the server and put the logs on a server.log and create another log file that will have  the last 2 lines of the logs (temp.log)

Log Checker - After the tail logger, This function will run and will find the a certain words on the temp.log.

Example:

This will find a strings "The task complete" if the checker find this it will make a variable from set X=0 to set X=1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findstr /?` from the prompt will guide you.

```
`findstr /L /c:"The task complete" "logfilename" >nul
```

will set `errorlevel` to 0 if found 1 otherwise (strictly not-0 otherwise, as "filemissing" produces errorlevel=2, I believe)

Comment: check like this: `if ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo ERRORLEVEL is 1 or higher) & (goto :end)`

Comment: I have rarely seen FINDSTR return anything other than 0 or 1. I've tested the missing file case, and many others. The only other return value I have seen is 255 when the regex contains more than 15 character class terms (a very nasty error that requires user interaction to dismiss a pop-up window).

Comment: @dbenham : conflicting options, eg `FINDSTR /l /r "abc" "%filename1%"`